# How can I silence warnings from all pods except local pods?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm assuming something along the lines of

```
post_install do |installer|

  # Debug symbols
  installer.pod_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if ? == ?
        config.build_settings['?'] = '?'
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar problem today and figured out two ways to achieve this depending on the complexity of your dependencies.

The first way is simple and should work if your local development pods are in your main pod file and not nested in another dependency. Basically inhibit all the warnings as per usual, but specify false on each local pod:

```ruby
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'LocalPod', :path => '../LocalPod', :inhibit_warnings => false
pod 'ThirdPartyPod',
```

The second way which is more comprehensive and should work for complex nested dependencies is by creating a whitelist of your local pods and then during post install, inhibit the warnings of any pod that is not part of the whitelist:

```ruby
$local_pods = Hash[
  'LocalPod0' => true,
  'LocalPod1' => true,
  'LocalPod2' => true,
]

def inhibit_warnings_for_third_party_pods(target, build_settings)
  return if $local_pods[target.name]
  if build_settings["OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS"].nil?
    build_settings["OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS"] = "-suppress-warnings"
  else
    build_settings["OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS"] += " -suppress-warnings"
  end
  build_settings["GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS"] = "YES"
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      inhibit_warnings_for_third_party_pods(target, config.build_settings)
    end
  end
end
```

This will now only inhibit 3rd party dependencies but keep the warnings on any local pods.

Comment: I tried by it seems that 3rd party dependencies used in LocalPod0 still shows warning when compiled

Comment: @xi.lin did you update the hash map on the 2nd code snippet? I've just tried the given code and works as described

Answer (score 2):

**Podfile Solution**

While `ignore_all_warnings` is an all or none proposition, you can `:inhibit_warnings => true` on any individual pod in the Podfile.

```
# Disable warnings for each remote Pod
pod 'TGPControls', :inhibit_warnings => true

# Do not disable warnings for your own development Pod
pod 'Name', :path => '~/code/Pods/'
```

Comment: I'm aware of this option and this is not what I'm looking for. I want to do this dynamically as I don't want to manually list every dependency and subdependency to silence those warnings as well.

Comment: Also, I would need to know about every dependency (which may change when I do pod update). I have to write a podfile which knows everything.

Comment: Conundrum, indeed. Ideally, Pods would not have warnings in the first place. Do you have examples of such warnings? Maybe we can pull-fix-push some of these pods, assuming they are on Github?

Answer (score 0):

There's CocoaPods plugin, https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-developing-folder that has `inhibit_warnings_with_condition`. Citing the [README](https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-developing-folder#-inhibit-warnings-for-specific-pods):

> Inhibit warnings for specific pods
>
> Add the following to your podfile
>
> ```
> plugin 'cocoapods-developing-folder'
>
> inhibit_warnings_with_condition do |pod_name, pod_target|
>     # your condition written in ruby, like:
>     # `not pod_name.start_with? "LE"` or
>     # `['Asuka', 'Ayanami', 'Shinji'].include? pod_name`
> end
> ```
>
> pod_target is a instance of Pod::PodTarget class, containing many more
>   info than the name. You can use it to set up complex rules.
>
> This function will override the warning inhibition settings by the
>   original methods, like: inhibit_all_warnings!, pod 'Ayanami',
>   :inhibit_warnings => true

So if you know the names of the local pods you can filter them like shown in the above example. Or you can try something like this (that tries to exploit the fact that local pods are not under Pods directory):

```
inhibit_warnings_with_condition do |pod_name, pod_target|
  pod_target.file_accessors.first.root.to_path.start_with? pod_target.sandbox.root.to_path
end
```

Beware that, if I get the last statement there correctly, it will *rule out* `inhibit_all_warnings!` and `:inhibit_warnings` from effect (I checked the [implementation](https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-developing-folder/blob/bf7d4fde9639dd71352b4541a951fe41e48b2961/lib/cocoapods-developing-folder/inhibit_warnings_with_condition.rb#L21) and it looks like it's indeed the case). So you can *not* use both `inhibit_warnings_with_condition` and `inhibit_all_warnings!` or `:inhibit_warnings`, but at the end, that kind of makes sense.