# Swift compiler error: Header not found

Tags: ios, swift, header, xcode6, cocoapods

I started a "Cocoa Touch Static Project" with a Cocoa Pods dependance.

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.4'

inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'project' do
pod 'libPusher', '~> 1.6'
end

target 'project' do

end
```

A workspace has been created by the command "pod install".

Then I created un swift project on this workspace and I created a Bridge header between this swift project and my Objective-C library project.

My swift project configuration:

```
//:configuration = Debug
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = demo/demo-Bridging-Header.h

//:configuration = Release
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = demo/demo-Bridging-Header.h
```

When I compile my swift project, I obtain this error:

```
demo-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: In file included from /Users/XYZ/Projets/iOS/project/library/demo/demo/demo-Bridging-Header.h:5:

project.h:10:9: 'Pusher/PTPusherDelegate.h' file not found

Failed to import bridging header '/Users/XYZ/Projets/iOS/project/project/demo/demo/demo-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Do you know why the swift compiler doesn't found header file and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your bridging header is found. It is it's content that is incorrect. See response below. Tested.

Comment: Why `inhibit_all_warnings!`? You shouldn't get any warnings in the first place.

Comment: Because I obtain some errors from 'SocketRocket' (dependance of LibPusher) like:

.../SocketRocket/base64.c:183:10: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

.../SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.m:127:20: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'CC_LONG' (aka 'unsigned int')

etc...

Comment: As your number of pods grows, you probably want to inhibit warnings on a pod-to-pod basis: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644959/how-can-i-silence-warnings-from-all-pods-except-local-pods/31779324#31779324

Answer (score 1):

• Did you run `pod install` ?

> Installing SocketRocket (0.3.1-beta2)
>
> Installing libPusher (1.6)

• Did you open **demo.xcworkspace** (close Xcode project, open Xcode workspace)

If so, were is the correct `demo-Bridging-Header.h` content:

```
#import "Pusher.h"
#import "Pusher/PTPusherDelegate.h"
```

Comment: Yes I run pod install and I open the workspace created by pod.

In my project: I created a static library linked with Pusher (with CocoaPod) and linked with some .a (for linphone library) 

This library is linked with another project (swift project).

When I add #import <Pusher/PTPusherDelegate.h> into header file on my static library, I obtain error project.h:10:9: 'Pusher/PTPusherDelegate.h' file not found